# What causes a loud tone/noise in Blackmagic ATEM talkback?

Tags: blackmagic, noise

### Setup

I have a Blackmagic ATEM 4 M/E and one of their studio cameras. I have a headphone on the camera and an active speaker on the ATEM so I can hear talkback.

### Problem

There is a super loud whine/tone/whistle/noise. It is similar to a [1kHz square tone](https://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/). Even if I set volume to minimum it is hearable.

### What I tried

I tried to disconnect the cable going into "SDI in" from the camera. The tone is still there but only in the ATEM so the source has to be the mixer. I added a mic to the talkback XLR input but it can't be heard. I also tried to add a sound mixer to this same XLR input and even if I set volume to the max it can be barely heard but the tone is still super loud compared to it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Make sure none of the SDI outputs of the ATEM are routed back to its inputs.

### Talkback feedback loop

The ATEM uses SDI channel 15 and 16 for talkback. If you route one of your SDI outputs to the SDI inputs (either directly via a simple SDI cable or trough a system of devices like record/playback devices) you will get a feedback loop that causes this high tone.

### Possible solutions

The simplest solution is to break the loop by removing the cable/devices causing it. Obviously this way you will loose the functionality you tried to add trough it, like having M/E 1 PGM as one of your inputs so you can use it as an input on M/E 2, 3 or 4, so if you would like to keep the loop without the noise you have to deembed or redirect the audio from channel 15 and 16. You can use something like the [Decimator MD-HX Cross Converter](https://decimator.com/Products/MiniConverters/MD-HX/MD-HX.html) that can reroute SDI audio channels.